# pass an array in mysql statement using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to archive something like this:

```
$array['0']="ID='1'";
$array['1']="ID='2'";

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE {$array}");
```

This is a special condition and this is just an example; I'm not worried about security here as no value is passed by end user.  Array values are auto generated and can be any size so I can't pass them manually.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE ".implode(" OR ",$array)`? [`implode( string $glue , array $pieces )`](http://php.net/IMPLODE)

Answer (score 2):

only store the values in the array.

```
$array = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID IN ('".implode("','", $array)."')");
```

That will stick the array together and output somethin like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID IN('aaa','bbb','ccc')");
```

you could leave out the `'` if you only use Integers. But anything related to strings needs them in the SQL-statement, thus better use them from the getgo.

If you check for other things, you shoudl sticks thos with and `AND` or `OR` depending on how you want to check them and probably put them in different arrays

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID IN ('".implode("','", $array_1 )."') OR name IN ('".implode("','", $array_2 )."')");
```